# How to skip week in Logic App trigger Recurrence

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have a case when the logic app needs to run every other Monday. Is there any way to achieve this with a recurrence trigger?

[image]

I am unable to find some references in *Entre custom value* option in the frequency.

Answer (score 2):

In general, You can set the recurrence trigger's frequency to week and from Add new parameters dropdown select `On these days`. From there you can select the day as per your requirement. Below is the screenshot of my recurrence trigger.

[image]

If you wish to run every other Monday you can set the interval to 2.

[image]